# Vue return v-model name by method

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm creating a rates per hour form. I have all the categories in my database rates table. I'd like to be able to grow the categories and it will automatically grow the fields on my form.. loop through it all.

The user needs to select a begin to end rate. I start at this rate and end at this rate.

So right now I have these values in json being loaded onto my page:

> rateCategories: [ { "name": "Local", "input1": "Local$0", "input2":
>   "Local$1" }, { "name": "International", "input1": "International$0",
>   "input2": "International$1" }, { "name": "Weekdays", "input1":
>   "Weekdays$0", "input2": "Weekdays$1" }, { "name": "Weekends",
>   "input1": "Weekends$0", "input2": "Weekends$1" } ]
>
> userRates: { "Local$0": 10, "Local$1": 25, "International$0": 300,
>   "International$1": 400, "Weekdays$0": 100, "Weekdays$1": 200,
>   "Weekends$0": 200, "Weekends$1": 300 }

What I'm doing is looping through rateCategories array to create the form. I need to dynamically create the v-model name for all the input fields to match the keys in userRates...

This is where it stops working! It will create the v-model name for me if I write:

```
:v-model.number="'userRates.'+rateCategories.name+'$0'"
```

but it won't compute it with the value from the user array. I do get a value into an input field if I write out the v-model name without creating it dynamically like this:

```
v-model.number="userRates.Weekdays$0"
```

but then the form needs to be manually updated every time a new category is added.

Is it really impossible to have a dynamic v-model name?? Why??

Also if that's so, how do I go about this so the page can loop through the categories when added to the database and not need a manual update to the page when categories are added or taken away??

Note: I'm also using Vuex store, so I'd rather it not break anything with my getter and setter functions too

Comment: Have you tried: `userRates[rateCategories.name$0]`  ?

Comment: I was having the hardest time! I tried yours but with an edit: model.number="userRates[`${rateCategories.name}$0`]" and this worked. Thanks so much! Add as an answer so I can check as the answer :)

Comment: And to others having issues.. I wrote the name of the input as: :name="'userRates.'+rateCategories.name+'$0'"

Comment: And for my vee-validate errors I wrote out like: 
{{ errors.first( userRates.${rateCategories.name}$0 ) }}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vue.js has full javascript expression support in data bindings, so an object's property can be accessed like you would in plain javascript.

Have you tried using `userRates[rateCategories.name$0]` ?

[Using Javascript Expressions in Vue.js](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Using-JavaScript-Expressions)